# Using Guice to inject a list(or set) of GraphQL Resolvers

Tags: java, kotlin, guice, graphql, graphql-java

Is it possible to use Guice to inject a List (or Set) of GraphQLResolvers?

The GraphQLResolver interface has the following signature:

`public interface GraphQLResolver<DataClass>`

I am using a Multibinder, and guess I need to resolve the type

`GraphQLResolver<? extends DataClass>`

so I would end up with the following (in Kotlin)

`val resolverBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), GraphQLResolver::class.java)
    resolverBinder.addBinding().to(BookResolver::class.java)
    resolverBinder.addBinding().to(AuthorResolver::class.java)`

The class signature I would like to inject to would be along the lines of

    `class SchemaLoaderImpl @Inject constructor(resolvers: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards GraphQLResolver>`

Comment: Are you sure this has _really_ anything to do with GraphQL? It sounds like you're asking a general Guice (or Guice+Kotlin) question: how to inject all instances of a generic interface (or something along those lines).

Comment: Effectively yes, this could be asked in a more general context, I was using graphQL as it was the particular case I had at the time.

Comment: I just think it needlessly limited your chances to get an answer, as now your question targets a tiny niche of Kotlin+Guice+graphql-java users.